# How to manipulate the projectIdentifiers/app identifier in the "before-prepare"-hook in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

Is there a way to change/manipulate the application id (*com.somename.xyz*) via a specific hook (e.g. before-prepare) in NativeScript (6.3)?

We're using a white-label application (multiple clients from the same code base) with some symbolic links to use different CSS file, fonts etc. and want to change the package name programmatically:

File: `/hooks/before-prepare/app-identifier.js`

```js
module.exports = function ($logger, $projectData, $injector, hookArgs) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $projectData.projectIdentifiers.ios = 'com.somename.xyz'
    $projectData.projectIdentifiers.android = 'com.somename.xyz'
    resolve()
  })
}
```

...but the application is starting with

"*Successfully synced application **com.brand.abc** on device emulator...*"

(defined in our package.json)

Comment: Are you sure your hooks are running, did you check by making some logs?

Comment: The hook seems to be running correctly. $projectData.projectIdentifiers are changed in the logs...but are unchanged in other/later hooks ("after-prepare" or "before-install")

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in an `after-prepare` hook - for Android by modifying the `strings.xml` file and for iOS by editing `plist`:

```
var plist = require('simple-plist');
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");

module.exports = function($logger, $projectData, hookArgs) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const platformFromHookArgs = hookArgs && (hookArgs.platform || (hookArgs.prepareData && hookArgs.prepareData.platform));
        const platform = (platformFromHookArgs  || '').toLowerCase();
        var env = (hookArgs.platformSpecificData || hookArgs.prepareData).env;
        if (platform === 'ios') {
            let infoFile = path.join($projectData.platformsDir, "ios", $projectData.projectName, $projectData.projectName + '-Info.plist');
            if (fs.existsSync(infoFile) && env && env.version ) {
                let parts = env.version.split('.');
                let data = plist.readFileSync(infoFile);
                if (env.environment && env.environment !== 'prod') {
                    data.CFBundleDisplayName = env.environment + ' - ' + data.CFBundleDisplayName
                }
                plist.writeFileSync(infoFile, data);
            }
        }
        if (platform === 'android') {
            infoFile = path.join($projectData.platformsDir, 'android','app', 'src', 'main', 'res','values', 'strings.xml');
            if (fs.existsSync(infoFile) && env && env.environment && env.environment !== 'prod')  {
                let contents = fs.readFileSync(infoFile,'utf8');
                contents = contents.replace(/MyNativeScriptAppName/g, env.environment + ' - MyNewEnvname');
                fs.writeFileSync(infoFile, contents);
            }                
        }
        resolve();
    });
}
```

Note that the above assumes environment variables being set in the `tns build` command. This can be done by using the `DefinePlugin` for webpack:

```
// Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                "process.env": {
                    environment: (env && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(env, 'environment')) ? JSON.stringify(env.environment) : undefined
                },
            }),
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - but you're changing the application name...not the application ID (defined in the package.json -> nativescript -> id)

Comment: True, but the above can be used for this purpose as well. In my build pipeline (Azure Devops) the app-id is just changed directly after checkout of the repo (based on an environment variable):

      - bash: |

          sed -i.bak 's/my.app.id/my.app.id_'$(BACKEND_ENV)'/' package.json